# Cloudflare zero trust application return SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Tags: ssl-certificate, cloudflare, gitlab

I am trying to secure a self-hosted GitLab solution using Cloudflare zero trust.
I followed their [tutorial](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/gitlab/) but when adding the DNS record I get 'This hostname is not covered by a certificate'. but I ignored it since the tutorial doesn't mention anything about HTTPS, and they even configure the ingress to work on HTTP.

When I try entering my website after finishing the configuration I get
'SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP' I tried multiple browsers and tried adding let's encrypt certificate but it didn't help.

Did they omit something in their tutorial? or am I doing something wrong?